# scipy tripple vector integral

Tags: python, scipy, calculus

I want to integrate a three dimensional function. Let's define the function as:

```
def pi(x, y, z): return x + y ** 2 + z ** 3
```

as a simple example. Let's choose the domain to be `[0,1]x[0,2]x[0,3]`. [According to wolframalpha, the desired integration result is 18.5.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20int_0%5E2%20int_0%5E3%20(x%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E3)dx%20dy%20dz) Here is the first thing I tried. I create a 3D tensor of pi(x,y,z) evaluations then do 3 1D integrations:

```
from scipy.integrate import trapz
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = np.linspace(0, 2)
z = np.linspace(0, 3)
print(trapz(trapz(trapz(pi(x[:, None, None], y[None, :, None], z[None, None, :]), x), y), z)) # 51.51853394418992
```

Notice that my output is incorrect. I think this went wrong because I did not have the correct order of integration. The next thing I tried was to explicitly reference 3D tensors of x, y, and z. This leads to an unexpected shape mismatch associated with the first trapz call:

```
print(trapz(trapz(trapz(pi(x[:, None, None], y[None, :, None], z[None, None, :]), x[:, None, None]), y[None, :, None]), z[None, None, :]))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4523, in trapz
    ret = (d * (y[slice1] + y[slice2]) / 2.0).sum(axis)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,1,0) (50,50,49)
```

So, I am in confusion. How can I perform the desired integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Wolfram example, your integrals are, from the inside out: integrating on x from 0 to **3**, then on y from 0 to 2, and finally on z from 0 to **1**.  But in your code, you have x going from 0 to 1 and z going from 0 to 3. When I put in those different ranges, I get `18.502290712203248`:

```
def pi(x, y, z):
    return x + y ** 2 + z ** 3

x = np.linspace(0, 3) # To three!
y = np.linspace(0, 2)
z = np.linspace(0, 1) # To one!

# I broke this up here, just to make it easier for me to read and debug.
x_int = trapz(pi(x[:, None, None], y[None, :, None], z[None, None, :]), x)
y_int = trapz(x_int, y)
z_int = trapz(y_int, z)
print(z_int)
```

Comment: Or analogously [`51.5` on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E3+int_0%5E2+int_0%5E1+(x+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+z%5E3)dx+dy+dz).